# Flex - RichTextEditor losing styling after view change

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe

It seems like there is a bug in flex's RichTextEditor that on change of view(view state change) the RTE loses its formatting. Has anyone encountered this issue before and know how to solve it. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:base="ui.components.base.*" xmlns:ui="ui.*" xmlns:local="*">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function click_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace(this.rte.htmlText);
                this.currentState = "other";

            }

            protected function clickother_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                this.currentState = "normal"
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal"/>
        <s:State name="other"/>
    </s:states>

    <s:VGroup includeIn="normal">
        <mx:RichTextEditor id="rte">

        </mx:RichTextEditor>
        <s:Button id="click" x = "500" y = "500" click="click_clickHandler(event)">

        </s:Button>
    </s:VGroup>

    <s:VGroup includeIn="other" >
        <s:Label>
            test
        </s:Label>
        <s:Button id="clickother" click="clickother_clickHandler(event)">
        </s:Button>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

i have faced that issue and solution is applying style external.

means when view is changed apply that css to rte.

Have a nice day....

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the content is inputted by the user.

Comment: for some reason flex is not working in my PC so i will explain you the situation.

When you change the view call any function
if(selectedChild == rte)
{
   rte.setStyle = "";
}

I am not sure about the code snippets so please check on google about setStyle. you need to change if condition that if selected child is RTE then that code will be executed.

Comment: Hope you will understand and sorry for not providing the exact code because flex is not working in my PC.

Comment: Has anyone found a fix for the issue, sorry that I am unable to understand your above comments.